# How to Count two array in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach, laravel-blade

Hi everybody here I have 2 paths so I return 2 arrays of tasks I need to count each array So in last I get

[6, 4]

```
@foreach ($path->pathtags as $Tag)    
    @foreach ($Tag->Tasks as $Task) 
        @if (!in_array($Task->id,$a))
            <li class="list-group-item"> Task : {{ $Task->task_name }}  </li>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: use php **count** function in your code to count your array. [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: Your question still isn't clear enough, we all answered to this, you made a change but still not enough... "how to count two arrays and get another one" . Maybe count the array where `in_array($Task->id, $a)` , not sure what you really want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest php way of counting arrays is `count($array)` so if you want to make a new array with the 2 array counts you can do it like this:

```
$counts = [count($array1), count($array2)];
```

But if you need to count the records in the database, you will need to change the query instead of `->get()` you will need to use `->count()`.

Comment: Can't  do that because i have to get data from it and I'm doing  some code to it because it returns duplicated data and i'm filtering it in the blade

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$path = count($path->pathtags);
$task = count($Tag->Tasks);
```

**Updated answer**

```
$path = count($path->pathtags);
@foreach ($path->pathtags as $Tag)
    $task = count($Tag->Tasks);
    @foreach ($Tag->Tasks as $Task) 
        <li class="list-group-item"> Task : {{ $Task->task_name }}  </li>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: return 1 I need to count arrays values

Comment: @KareemElsharkawy: please show me reslult (i.e print('<pre style="color:red;">');
        print_r($path->pathtags);
        print('</pre>');
        exit;)

Comment: So you Can understand Path have  many tags and tags have many  tasks

Comment: Same it return 1

Comment: can't use your  code because if function i have updated my code please check